# Deepin could not resolve host when running Git clone

Tags: linux, debian, git

I'm having a problem when I try to make `git clone`. Deepin 15.9.3 distribution. I'm use this command:

```
git clone "https://gitportoprd.portoseguro.brasil/...."
```

and I received this error:

```
Cloning into 'COL'...
fatal: unable to access 
'https://gitportoprd.portoseguro.brasil/....': Could 
not resolve host: gitportoprd.portoseguro.brasil
```

But, I can access through the browser and we don't have a proxy server between them.

Obs.: I can access when I put the IP insted of the server name

Comment: `.brasil` isn't a [valid "tld"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), so you must be using some custom DNS in your browser. How did you find out the IP?

Comment: I discovered through another Windows computer

Comment: So it's really a matter of figuring out what DNS that Windows computer is using. FWIW, 8.8.8.8 (Google's DNS) can't resolve `gitportoprd.portoseguro.brasil`. Maybe ask your IT support?

Comment: @JakeGould Given that Debian is currently on version 9, it's more likely the OP meant [Deepin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepin) - the pre-edit name *almost* matches and the version matches.

Comment: @Bob Now that’s a good observation! Corrected.